# How I can get date from Message kit in Swift firebase

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on message Kit and I want to get the date from the message kit, But I'm getting an error while used it. I've chatDashboardView Controller and I've defined the computed property (getFormatter) and above the chatdashboard I've defined the Message struct.

```
 public static var getFormatter: String{
        let dformatter = DateFormatter()
        dformatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyy HH:mm"
        let dateToString = dformatter.string(from: Date())
        return dateToString
    }

struct Message: MessageType{
    public var sender: SenderType
    public var messageId: String
    public var sentDate: Date
    public var kind: MessageKind
}
```

In networking class want to access this getFormatter property its saying me (Cannot call value of non-function type 'String') this is the error see the code and guide me thanks

```
func getAllMessagesForConverstion(id:String,compltion:@escaping(Result<[Message],Error>) -> Void){
        checkMessageUSer(id) { (user) in
            guard let users = user else {print("not getting the users sorry on getllMessage");return}
            let messages : [Message] = users.compactMap({dic in
                guard let content = dic["content"] as? String,
                      let dateString = dic["date"] as? String,
                      let messageId = dic["id"] as? String,
                      let isRead = dic["is_read"] as? String,
                      let senderEmail = dic["sender_email"] as? String,
                      let typeMessage = dic["type"] as? String,
                      let name = dic["name"] as? String,
                      let dateData = ChatDashboard.getFormatter(from: dateString)  else
                      {return nil}
                
                let senderData = Sender(photo: "", senderId: senderEmail, displayName: name)
                return Message(sender: senderData, messageId: messageId, sentDate: "", kind: .text(content))
                //return Message(sender: senderData, messageId: messageId, sentDate: , kind: .text(content))
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is a guy that you refer to as 'Firebase,' and how does it come into play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getFormatter` computed property is a `string`, which is a string format of today (`Date()`)

Seeing what you are trying to do, you need to change the `getFormatter` like below (better if you could rename it to something like `formatter` since it is a property not a method)

```
    public static var formatter: DateFormatter {
       let dformatter = DateFormatter()
       dformatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyy HH:mm"
       return dformatter
   }
```

then you can access it and use to format your date string like below in `getAllMessagesForConverstion`

```
let dateData = ChatDashboard.formatter.date(from: dateString)
```

Comment: SamB but why you used dateToString when i'm writing this error occurs out of scope

Comment: I'm getting an error can you please what is dateToString ?

Comment: If you change your existing `public static var getFormatter: String{}` with the answer `public static var formatter: DateFormatter {}`, then there is no `dateToString` anymore